# I have two git commits that appear the same after a pushed amend

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, git-amend

I have a git branch that I am working on locally.  After editing some code and doing a commit and a push to a remote repo, I noticed that I had an error in my commit message.  I used amend to correct this.  First I tried to push, but this was not allowed,  So I did a pull and then a push.  Everything appeared to work.  When I look at the repo, I can see two commits, one for each message (both correct and incorrect, so I guess my correction was useless lol.)  Then I noticed that both commits contained the same code changes.  This seems strange, because I don't think that both should contain code changes.  Does this mean that the changes are applied twice?  Is this a problem that could cause issues later?  Does this need to be fixed?  If so, how do I fix this?

=====

commands

1. (IDE) Changes made, added and committed
2. git push -u origin BRANCH_NAME
3. (IDE) Amend performed
4. git push (error: failed to push some refs)
5. git pull
6. git push

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in git as an edited commit. *A commit can never be changed* once it exists.

What "amend" does is to start with an existing *original* commit and create a *new* commit containing the same files (what you incorrectly call "code changes") as the original commit and pointing to the same parent as the original commit.

The original commit is neither changed nor destroyed by this process, though if no ref ultimately points to it, it may go out of existence after a while as being unreachable.

Comment: I'm afraid that without more details, as to what you actually did (i.e. every command you actually gave to git and what git said in reply, and/or what the state of the repo is now), that is the best answer I can give. But at least it should make you a bit less concerned about the fact that you see two commits with the same content; that is not a surprise.

Comment: Sounds like an amend is a copy of a commit, and it should contain all of the changes that the previous commit held.  Having those two commits apply the same changes twice should not cause a problem.

Comment: Should I update the question to say "contained the same files" ?

Comment: Well, they shouldn't both be part of the same chain either. If they are, it seems something went wrong; if you started with `A-B` and your goal was `A-Bamended` and you have instead `A-B-Bamended`, that's wrong. You can fix that by squashing `Bamended` onto `B` (interactive rebase is the simplest way).

Comment: I don't know about updating the question. I'm just trying to impress upon you the other grand fact about commits: a commit contains not changes but files, and in particular _every commit contains **all** the files_. That, and the rule about commits being unchangeable, are the two _first_ things to know about git.

Comment: I'm curious whether you are the only user of this repo. If so I can suggest what went wrong and how you could have fixed it. :)

Comment: There are 3 users

Comment: So you could have pushed with `--force-with-lease`. If no one else had pushed to this branch in the meantime, that would have pushed the amended commit directly to replace the original. But in general you should not attempt to rewrite history, not even with `amend`, in a shared branch.

Comment: I think that the local repo showed "A-B" after the first commit and "A-Bamended" right after the amend.  However, this changed to "A-B-Bamended" locally after the pull - push.

Comment: "--force-with-lease" is what I found was the correct procedure too.  but now that I used amend, do you think I need to try to fix it?  or just keep moving forward and consider it to be just a sloppy mistake?

Comment: As I said earlier, you could squash B out of existence with no trouble. Again you'd probably have to `force-with-lease` to push that change.

Answer (score 0):

As [matt said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62091078/1256452), you can't actually *change* a commit.  What `git commit --amend` does is make a new commit that *doesn't* **extend** the current branch.

I think more people get this when they can see, visually, what this means.  But this means you first need to learn to draw commit graphs.  Since you are using an IDE, perhaps you have already learned this—but you don't mention which IDE (and I don't normally use any IDE anyway myself).  Also, it's very hard to type graphics into a StackOverflow posting. :-) So consider this text version of a drawing of a commit graph:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

What we have here is a series of commits, all in a nice neat line, with the commit whose hash is `H`—`H` here stands in for some big ugly Git hash ID—being *last* in the chain.  Some IDEs draw this vertically, with commit `H` at the top:

```
H  <commit subject line>
|
G  <commit subject line>
|
:
```

but for StackOverflow purposes I like the horizontal drawings.

Note how each commit "points back" to its immediate *parent* commit.  Internally, this means that each commit stores the full hash ID of its parent, because Git actually *finds* commits by their hash IDs.

To find commit `H` specifically (and quickly), Git needs to have its hash ID stored somewhere too.  Git can use `H` to find `G`'s hash ID, and then can use `G` to find `F`'s hash ID, and so on, but Git needs to *start* with `H`'s hash ID.  The place Git *finds* `H`'s hash ID is your branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

The *branch name* lets Git find `H` easily, because the branch name itself contains the raw commit hash ID.  Then commit `H` lets Git find `G` easily, which lets Git find `F` easily, and so on.  That's our backwards-looking chain of commits.

Note how when you have multiple branches, they tend to rejoin somewhere in the past:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Here, we made `branch1` have two commits that aren't on `master` yet, and made `branch2` have two commits that aren't on `master` yet either.  The commits up through `H` are on *all three branches*.  The name `master` specifically means *commit `H`*, but also—whenever necessary—means *all commits up to and including `H`*.  The name `branch1` means commits up to and including `J`, or just `J`, depending on context; and the name `branch2` means commits up through `H` plus `K-L`, or just `L`, depending on context.

I've drawn the name `HEAD` in here attached to `branch2` to show that we have `branch2`, and hence commit `L`, checked out at the moment.  The general idea with Git is this:

- Git will resolve `HEAD` to a commit, by finding the branch name and following the branch name's arrow to the commit.
- That's the *current commit* and is the one you have checked out.
- Each commit finds a previous (parent) commit, which defines the chain of commits that we call "the branch".
- But the word *branch* is ambiguous, because sometimes it means *the branch name*, sometimes it means *the commit at the tip of the branch as pointed to by the name*, and sometimes it means *the tip commit plus some or all previous commits*.

When people use the word *branch*, sometimes they mean a series of commits up to and including a commit that's *not* identified by a *branch name*, too.  Besides regular branch names, Git has *tag* names, and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` and `origin/branch1` and so on.  All of these names ultimately just point to one specific commit—just like a branch name—but only *branch* names have the feature of letting `HEAD` attach to them.

#### Consider now how adding a commit normally works

Suppose we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

We have the files from commit `H` checked out, because `H` is the *current commit*.  We make some changes to those files, `git add` the updated files to copy the changes over top of the copies of those files in Git's *index* or *staging area*, and run `git commit`.  Git now freezes the files that are in its index, add the right metadata—our name and email address, our log message, the parent hash ID `H`, and so on—and thereby creates a new commit, which gets a new unique big ugly hash ID but we'll just call it `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          I
```

Since `I` is now the *last* commit, Git now does the one trick that makes branch names different from any other kind of name: Git stores `I`'s hash ID into the *name* `branch`, because that's the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  We get:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

which we can straighten out now:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

So this is how `git commit` works:

- It freezes, for all time, all the files that are in Git's *index* (aka the *staging area*).  The fact that Git makes commits from its ready-to-freeze copies in its staging area, rather than the ordinary files you have in your work-tree, is why you have to `git add` files all the time.  These frozen files become the new snapshot in the new commit.
- It adds the appropriate metadata: your name, your email address, the current date-and-time, and so forth.
- It sets the *new* commit's parent hash ID to the *current* commit's hash ID.
- It writes out the actual commit (which gains a new, unique hash ID).
- Last, it writes the new commit's hash ID into the *current branch **name*** so that the name continues to point to the *last* commit in the chain.

Having written out the new commit, the current commit changes—the hash ID that `HEAD` means is now commit `I` instead of commit `H`—but once again the *current* commit snapshot matches the files in Git's *index*, which—if you `git add`-ed everything—also match the files in your work-tree.

#### Now we can see how `git commit --amend` works

When you use `git commit --amend`, Git goes through all the same steps as for any commit, with one exception: the new commit's *parent* (or parents, plural, if the current commit is a merge commit) are *taken from* the current commit instead of *being* the current commit.  That is, rather than doing:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

with new commit `J` pointing back to existing commit `I`, Git does this:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--G--H--J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

In effect, the then-current commit `I` has now been "shoved out of the way" to place the new commit at the end of the chain *without making the chain any longer*.

The existing commit `I` still exists.  It just no longer has a *name*.

#### When you involve another Git repository, you exchange *commits* with them

Git is, at its heart, really all about *commits*.  You make new commits, and then you have your Git call up another Git and send it your commits.  Or, you call up that other Git repository—whether or not you yourself have made any new commits—and *get* any new commits that they have, that you don't.

One of these two commands is `git fetch`.  That's the one that calls up their Git and finds which commits they have that you don't: it fetches their commits into your own Git repository.

The other command is `git push`: with `git push` you have your Git call up their Git and *send* commits.  These two are not quite symmetric, though.  Let's look at `git fetch` first, because it's where *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` and `origin/branch` come from.

We've already seen that Git *finds* commits by taking a name—maybe a branch name—to find the *last* commit, and then working backwards.  Meanwhile, your Git is calling up some other Git.  That other Git has branch names B1, B2, B3, ..., each of which specify the *last* commit's hash ID, for *that* Git's branches.

Those are *their* branches, not *your* branches.  You may or may not have branches with the same name, but those are *their* names, pointing to *their* last commits.  Your `git fetch` doesn't touch *your* branch names.

Suppose, for instance, that we start with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

but that we got commit `H` *from* `origin`.  Then we really have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

That is, in *their* Git repository, *their* name `master` also selects commit `H`.  So our Git has recorded their Git's name `master` as our `origin/master`; then we made our `master` from their `origin/master`, and now both names point to existing commit `H`.

If we now make our own new commit `I`, *our* master now points to commit `I`.  Our `origin/master` still points to `H` as before:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Meanwhile, suppose that they—whoever *they* are—make their own new commit.  It will get some big ugly unique hash ID; we'll just call it `J`.  Their commit `J` is in *their* repository:

```
...--G--H--J   <-- master [in their Git]
```

We run `git fetch`, and our Git calls up their Git and finds that they have a new commit that we have never seen before.  Our Git gets it from their Git and puts it into our repository.  To remember `J`'s hash ID, our Git updates our own `origin/master`:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
```

(I put ours up top just for aesthetics—I like the letters to be more in alphabetical order here).

Now we have a problem, of sorts.  Our commit `I` and their commit `J` form two branches, depending on just what we mean by the word *branch:*

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/master
```

We'll need to combine these somehow, at some point.  We can do that with `git merge`, or we can use `git rebase` to copy our existing commit `I` to a new and improved commit—let's call it `I'`—that extends their `J`:

```
          I   ??? [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
            \
             I'  <-- master (HEAD)
```

We abandon our `I` in favor of our new-and-improved `I'`, which adds on to their existing commits.  We can now `git push origin master`.  Or, we use `git merge` to combine work into a *new* commit, with a snapshot made by a slightly complicated process involving comparing commit `H`'s snapshot to each of the two snapshots in `I` and `J`:

```
          I
         / \
...--G--H   M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \ /
          J   <-- origin/master
```

Once again we can now `git push origin master`.

#### Why push is not symmetric with fetch

Let's say we have just this:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/master
```

In other words, we have not yet rebased or merged.  Our name `master` points to commit `I`; our name `origin/master`, representing the `master` over on `origin`, points to commit `J`.  We can *try* to run:

```
git push origin master
```

which will call up their Git, send them our commit `I`—they don't have it yet because we have not given it to them before—and then ask them to set *their* `master` to point to commit `I`.

Remember that their `master` currently points to (shared, copied into both Gits) commit `J`.  If they do what we ask, they will end up with:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   ??? [abandoned]
```

That is, *they* will *lose* commit `J` entirely.  Git *finds* commits by starting from a branch name like `master` and working backwards.  Their `master` used to find `J`; and if they take our request, to set their `master` to point to `I` instead, they won't be able to find `J` any more.

This is why they just refuse our polite request, saying *not a fast forward*.  We fix this problem by using `git rebase` or `git merge`, to make `I'` or some merge commit.  Then we either send them `I'` and ask them to set their `master` to point to `I'`, which is OK because `I'` comes *after* `J` and therefore keeps commit `J` in the picture; or, we send them `M` (and `I` again, if they dropped it), and ask them to set their `master` to point to `M`, which is OK because *both `I` and `J`* come before `M`, so that they can still find `J`.

#### Sometimes we really want them to throw out a commit

When we use `git commit --amend`, we take a chain like this:

```
...--H--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and turn it into this:

```
       I   ??? [abandoned]
      /
...--H--J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

which makes commit `I` appear to go away.  It actually sticks around for a while—at least a month or so—in case we want it back, through a mechanism that Git calls *reflogs*.  But it's gone from the everyday view, as there's no name that points directly to it, and no other name that points to some commit that eventually points back to `I` either.

But what if we sent commit `I` to some other Git?  What if, in particular, we ran:

```
git push origin branch
```

so that we now have:

```
       I   <-- origin/branch
      /
...--H--J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

where our `origin/branch` represents `origin`'s `branch`, which now points to our old commit `I`?

If we just run:

```
git push origin branch
```

this tells their Git: *Here: have a new commit `J`.  Now please, if it's OK, set your `branch` to remember commit `J`.*  They will say no, for the same reason they said no to our other example: this will *lose* commit `I`, in their Git repository.

But that's exactly what we want.  We *want* them to lose commit `I` off their branch `branch`.  To make that happen, we send the same sort of operation—another `git push`—but we change our last polite request, into a more forceful command.

We have two options:

- We can say: *Set your name `branch` to point to commit `J`!*  This just tells them *drop all commits that might be dropped this way*, even if that's now `I` and `K` too.
- Or, we can say: *I think your `branch` identifies commit <hash-of-`I`>.  If so, change it to identify commit `J` instead.  In any case, let me know what happened.*

The first is a simple `git push --force`.  The second is `git push --force-with-lease`.  Our Git will fill in the "I think" commit `I` hash part from our `origin/branch`, and of course get commit `J`'s hash ID in the same way as always.

The danger of any `git push --force`, with or without the `-with-lease` part, is that we're telling some other Git *throw out some commits*.  That's what we want, of course, so it's not *that* dangerous, as long as we know that we're asking for commits to be thrown out.  But if we're `git push`-ing to a GitHub repository, are there *other* people who use that GitHub repository to `git fetch` from?  Maybe they have picked up our commit `I` and are using it.  They could put commit `I` back.  Or, maybe we are making extra work for them, such that they'll have to rework *their* commits to use commit `J` instead of commit `I`.

We should arrange in advance with other users of this `origin` Git, so that they know which branches might have commits *removed* like this.

#### Your own case

In your case, you did a `git push` that failed, then a `git pull`.  The `git pull` command means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  That second command is `git merge` by default.

So, let's say you started with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master, branch (HEAD)
```

then added commit `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

You then ran (successfully) `git push -u origin branch` which resulted in:

```
          I   <-- branch (HEAD), origin/branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

(again I just put `I` on top this time for aesthetics).

Next, you used `git commit --amend`, which made a new commit `J` that doesn't have `I` as its parent:

```
          I   <-- origin/branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

You tried a regular `git push`, which failed with *not a fast forward:* their Git told your Git that this push would lose commits (`I` in particular).

Then you ran `git pull`:

- This ran `git fetch`, which did nothing because you already have commits `H` and `I` and there are no changes to make to any of your `origin/*` names.
- Then it ran `git merge` to merge `I` and `J` into a new merge commit.

I'll stop drawing the *names* `master` and `origin/master` as they get in the way, but this did just what we'd now expect:

```
          I   <-- origin/branch
         / \
...--G--H   M   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \ /
          J
```

and then you ran `git push`, which sent them commits `J` and `M` to add on to their `branch`.  They said OK to that, so your Git updated your `origin/branch`:

```
          I
         / \
...--G--H   M   <-- branch (HEAD), origin/branch
         \ /
          J
```

and this is what you now see in your repository.

You can, if you like, force your name `branch` to point to commit `J` directly again, then use `git push --force-with-lease` to ask the other Git to discard both commits `M` and `I`.

To force your current (`HEAD`) branch to point to one specific commit, use `git reset`.  In this case, you might first make sure you have nothing else that `git reset --hard` will destroy, and use `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to move to the first parent of `M`.  See side note on first parent below.

(To move a branch that you're *not* on, use `git branch -f`, which needs two arguments: the branch name, and the commit to move-to.  Since `git reset` operations on the branch that you *are* on, `git reset` just takes the commit specifier.)

#### Side note: `--first-parent`

There's a tricky bit that is not shown well in my horizontal graph drawings.  Whenever you make a new *merge* commit like `M`, Git makes sure that the *first* of the multiple parents coming out of `M` points back to the commit that *was* the tip of your branch before.  In this case, that means the first parent of `M` is `J`, not `I`.

You can have `git log`, and other Git commands, only look at the *first* parent of each merge when viewing commits.  If you do this, the picture looks like this:

```
...--G--H--J--M   <-- branch (HEAD), origin/branch
```

In fact, `M` still points back to `I` too, as its second parent.

This `--first-parent` option is mainly useful to look at a branch like `master` when features are always developed on their own branches:

```
                  o--o--o   <-- feature2
                 /       \
 ...--●---------●---------●--...   <-- master
       \       /
        o--o--o   <-- feature1
```

Looking at `master` with `--first-parent` drops all those incoming side connections, so that one sees only the solid bullet commits.  But the notion itself matters whenever you are dealing with a merge commit: `M^1` means *the first parent of `M`* and `M^2` means *the second parent of `M`*.  The tilde suffix notation counts backwards through first-parent links only, so that `M~1` means *step back one first-parent link*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of amend probably you just made another one commit.
Your situation probably looks like this: c1 -> c2 -> c3 (where c2 is incorrect commit, c3 is not needed commit)
You need **-f** option, open terminal and try this:

1) git checkout my_branch
2) git reset --hard c2
3) change source code
4) git add .
5) git commit --amned
6) now your **wim** editor will open, and you can change commit msg
7) save changes in your vim editor and exit
8) git log (make sure that there are c1 -> c2 nothing more)
9) git push origin my_branch -f

In future amends do like this:
1) git checkout my_branch
2) git fetch
3) git pull
4) change source code
5) git add .
6) git commit --amend
7) now your **vim** editor will open, and you can change commit msg
8) save changes in your vim editor and exit
9) git push origin my_branch -f
Be careful **"force"** option is risky. When You use it, it means You are 100% sure You know what You are doing.